# Retake TimeTask thread after class has been destroyed

Tags: java, multithreading, timertask

I'm developing a countdown timer with TimeTask in Java EE. The event is attached to a button click (start/stop):

```
this.timer = new Timer("taskname");
this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {            
  public void run() {
    if (remainTime <= 0) {
        stopTimer();
    } else {
        remainTime--;                       
    }
    saveCurrentTimeOnDb(remainTime);
  }
}, 1000, 1000);

private void stopTimer() {
  if (timer != null) {
    this.timer.cancel();
    this.timer.purge();
  }
}
```

The timer value is showing on a label placed on the layout.

This is working ok. The problem occours when I reload the page. I want to retake the thread that is already started, instead, the Class is creating a new thread and the clock is running 2x fast.

I tried to do something like this:

```
Thread threadTimer = getThreadByName("taskname");

if (threadTimer != null) { // thread exists
    threadTimer.interrupt(); // destroying it

    currentTime = getCurrentTimeFromDb();

    createNewTimer(currentTime); // creates a new thread
}
```

The clock timer is saved on DB every second (this is a system requirement), so I can take the current time from it. I'm trying to cancell the old thread and creates a new one using the clock time that I already have.

The problem is: threadTimer.interrupt() is not destroying the timer thread, so when I create a new timer, I get two threads running again. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an InterruptedException.

For `java.util.Timer`, it does use `queue.wait()` in `mainloop()` method. I guess you just caught the `InterruptedException` but did nothing. So the `threadTimer` wasn't killed.

I suggest you check `threadTimer` in event listener. If it's not null and `isAlive()`, just return and do nothing. Or else, you can launch the thread.

Comment: My Thread.interrupt() is not throwing an InterruptedException exception...